# How to re-use asp.net control on the page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ascx

I'm using web forms and have same text in two different blocks.
HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <p>My text</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <p>My text</p>
</div>
```

I have to use asp.net controls. 
The code I'm using

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblText"></asp:Literal>
```

Is there any way to re-use this control for second text block instead of creating a clone of this control with another ID?

I can't use tags like `<%=` for this page.

Comment: In code behind use `lblText2.text = lblText.Text;`.

Comment: @VDWWD I know how to set text, but the question: is there any way to reuse this control and don't create another one?

Comment: Use a Repeater or create a User Control. Depends what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can encapsulate `asp: Literal` along with the HTML of your DIV within a `UserControl` and expose the`Text` property.

**MyText.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyText.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyText" %>
<div>
    <p>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblText" />
    </p>
</div>
```

**MyText.ascx.cs:**

```
using System.Web.UI;
public partial class MyText : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return lblText.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblText.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

***And using it in WebForm:***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register src="MyText.ascx" tagname="MyText" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:MyText ID="uc1MyText1" runat="server" Text="My text"/>
        <uc1:MyText ID="uc1MyText2" runat="server" Text="My text 2"/>
        <uc1:MyText ID="uc1MyText3" runat="server" Text="My text 3"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]